# Why does a JavaScript for loop always break my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have tried many variation to be sure its a for loop, but a basic for loop breaks my website

I'm using Spring boot and thymeleaf

In a html file we cam see :

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        console.log("Text");
    }
</script>
```

This breaks above, causing a error below
http://localhost:8090/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
Exception parsing document: template="AnnonymousLayout", line 147 - column 20 (home:1)

If i change it to this below it works :

```
<script>        
    console.log("Text");       
</script>
```

As I explained above I have tried many things to test different variations and it just doesn't make sense

Searching google doesn't help because all search results bring up continue and breaks posts for breaking out of loop

I'm following exactly this w3schools tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate)

Comment: That is not a Java for Loop

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Shot in the dark, what happens if you replace `i < 10` with `i != 10`? If that works when `i < 10` doesn't, then you have an issue with your framework.

Comment: The error is coming from Java, folks--look at the tags on the question and the fact that it's a 500 error from the server

Comment: @JAAulde The title....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194185/how-can-i-use-for-loop-in-javascript-using-thymeleaf <-- Did you search?

Comment: I think Niet the Dark Absol is onto something. thymeleaf can only handle valid XML. The `<` is probably throwing off the parse. Adding CDATA blocks inside the `script` may also help

Comment: epascarello wins!

Comment: it is serverside error.

Comment: Yes I didn't thing search "Thymeleaf", because not making any Thymeleaf calls in the script. I have made Thymeleaf calls in other scripts and have added CDATA comment in other files. Ill test them tags and come back.
@epascarello, & Jonathon Reinhart.. Yes its JavaScript. I want a JavaScript for loop. It's what the tutorial from w3schools is sharing. Why you say this Java? Thanks
JAAulde Why possible duplicate ? I didn't think search these keywords. I search "JavaScript for loop breaks site". I should have been smarter. Please dont mark duplicate. I'm trying be good boy :(

Comment: @JAAulde this is exactly what's happening and why the entire for-loop should be embedded wrapped in `/*<![CDATA[*/`. @DanielGadd there's nothing bad about your question being closed as a duplicate (and in this case it is I guess).